# What's the difference between name="" and :name=""

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If `:name="name"`, the value of the name attribute will be the unique data it gets from the props.

But if I use this way `name="name"` without the `:` than it will be just `"name"`.

What the `:` do with the name attribute?

Example code:

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div
            class="form-control"
            :name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'base-date',
    props: ['id', 'name', 'placeholder', 'type', 'value']
</script>
```

Comment: You can also check out the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is the short notation for [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) which binds one or more attributes, or a component prop to an expression dynamically.

On the other hand `name="name"` will add the string `'name'` as an attribute value for your property.